# How to get context path in thymelaef

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I develop Spring Boot app with Thymeleaf templates. I would like add prefix (server context path) to code below like `'serverContext/user/' + user.id`. I tried to change $ to @ but `user.id` was converted to string.

Thank you.

```
<tr th:each="user : ${users}">
    <td><a th:href="${ '/user/' + user.id}">View</a></td>
</tr>
```

**Edit:** Fixed by `<td><a th:href="@{/}+${ 'user/' + user.id}">View</a></td>`

Is any other solution there?

Answer (score 2):

in **application.properties**:

```
server.context-path=/test
```

**Service class:**

```
@Component("helperService")
public class HelperService {

    @Value("${server.context-path}")
    private String contextPath;

    public String getContextPath(){
        return contextPath;
    }
}
```

**Html file:**

```
<span th:text="${@helperService.getContextPath()}"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've this configuration with **Thymeleaf 3.1.2**, **Spring Boot 3.1.3** and **Java 17**:

Generate Service **"LocalService.java"**, annotate with ***@Component***

```
@Component("localService")
public class LocalService {

  @Autowired
  private ServletContext context;

  public String getContextPath() {
    return this.context.getContextPath();
  }
}
```

In HTML, Thymeleaf get service with ***@localService***:

```
<div th:content="${@localService.getContextPath()}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of [mrt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46560353/2576531) works, but provides an additional bean which is not necessary.
Just inject `ServerProperties` and call `getContextPath()`.

This bean is provided as `@ConfigurationProperties`and therefore is already available. See [ServerProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.html).

**BUT** this solves what you asked for, but your problem would not be a problem if you don't use absolute pathes. Why not use relative pathes like this:

```
<td><a th:href="${ 'user/' + user.id}">View</a></td>
```

this link would work assuming you are at `$host$/serverContext`

If you are on `$host$/serverContext/someOtherPath` and want to link to your users page the following would work:

```
<td><a th:href="${ '../user/' + user.id}">View</a></td>
```

and so on. There is no need to know the context path for this.

Comment: I deploy the web app as war file on Tomcat and I set context path using context.xml file. When I change path value from <Context path="/"/> to <Context path="/web-mvc"/> the href value doesn't change.